# How do I use camelCase correctly for three or more words e.g. amountOfColors or amountofColors?

Tags: camelcase

I'm a beginner, but competent at code and have some setbacks like this where it doesn't really matter- but I like making it easier and legible to understand my code.

Anyways, yeah. I just have problems with three word sentence fragments - should they be `amountOfColors` or `amountofColors`?

Comment: It's "amountOfColors". startWithALowercaseLetterAndThenCapitalizeEachWord. PascalCaseIsTheSameExceptYouAlsoCapitalizeTheFirstLetter. some_people_use_snake_case. css-guys-love-kebab-case.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović you should write that as an answer

Comment: Why do you think that three word identifiers are special? What makes you think they are treated differently than two word identifiers?

Comment: This reminds me that camelCase starts with a c and Terminates with a T ;-)

Answer (score 8):

It should be `amountOfColors`. Each word after the first should be capitalized.

The purpose of camelCase and other casing conventions is to indicate the words in multi-word identifiers when spaces can't be used.

There is some disagreement about how to capitalize acronyms and abbreviations. Should it be `toJSON` or `toJson`? In those cases you should follow the conventions of the language or platform.

It is not a good idea to make up your own conventions or team conventions, since this is going to clash with the standard library or third-party libraries and create confusion. Eg if you override `GetHashCode()` but call it `GetHashcode()` you have a bug - it is not just a question of taste.

Comment: "There is some disagreement about how to capitalize acronyms and abbreviations" – It has been over 20 years, but `XMLHttpRequest` still makes me sad.

Comment: Many many years ago, I always miscapitalized "hashcode" in Java.  Fortunately, they added the `@override` annotation and using that caught them all.  

**Moral:** use your language constructs and IDE / Linter!

Answer (score 0):

Technically with three words it becomes Bactrian Case

[image]